# Digits after the decimal QTableView delegate

Tags: c++, qt, delegates, qtableview

I need a specified number of digits after the decimal point for the items of QTableView, so I wrote a simple delegate.

```
class TableItemDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{

   Q_OBJECT

public:

   TableItemDelegate(QObject *parent = 0) : QStyledItemDelegate(parent) {}

   QString displayText(const QVariant & value, const QLocale & locale)
   {
     QString str = QString::number(value.toDouble(), 'f', 8);
     return str;
   }
};
```

But it doesn`t work, constructor called, but not the displayText() function.

```
TableItemDelegate *decDelegate = new TableItemDelegate(tableView);
tableView->setItemDelegate(decDelegate);
```

What I`m doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried QVariant::isValid or returning a hard-coded QString like "1.0000"?

Comment: The model, that been set for this view is already filled with data, I`m sure that QVariants are valid.http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/21/scrul.png/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method isn't called because you forgot the `const` specifier at the end of the function signature:

```
QString displayText(const QVariant & value, const QLocale & locale ) const
```