# how to set precision and alignment for displaying numeric values in QTableView

Tags: qt, format, precision, qtableview

What would be **the easiest** way to set fixed format to display numeric values in QTableView? I need to format as currency - so always show decimal part separator and 2 digits after it. Possibly align righ, maybe append a currency name.  Right now it shows as much as needed, eg:

- double `12.00` will be shown as `12`,
- double `12.10` will be shown as `12.1`,
- double `12.11` will be shown as `12.11`,

Is there an easy way to go? SetFormatForColumn or something like that? Can't finde enything really useful over that subject in the doc... 
At the moment I have subclassed `QStyledItemDelegate`. This works, but seems like a huge overhead, as only thing that my subclass does is reimplement 2 methods - as below:

```
QString CurrencyDelegate::displayText(const QVariant & value, const QLocale & locale) const {
    return locale.toCurrencyString(value.toDouble());
}
void CurrencyDelegate::paint(QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const {
    QStyleOptionViewItem myOption = option;
    (myOption.displayAlignment ^= Qt::AlignLeft) |= Qt::AlignRight;
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, myOption, index);
}
```

Is there an easier way? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Easiest way: Follow Joseph's advice.
Correct way: Subclass QStyleItemDelegate. Example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064149/digits-after-the-decimal-qtableview-delegate

Answer (score 4):

Return a `QString` from `QAbstractItemModel::data` using `QString::number`

```
QVariant YourTableModel::data(const QModelIndex & index, int32_t role) const
{
  if (!index.isValid()) {
    return QVariant();
  }

  if (role == Qt::DisplayRole || role == Qt::EditRole)
  {
    switch (index.column())
    {
    case YOUR_COL:
      double theDouble = getDoubleFromModelSomewhere();
      return QString::number(theDouble, 'f', 2);  // Format shows 2 decimals
    }
  }

  return QVariant();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is easier. Was looking rather for something "out of the box". In both solutions (your and mine) I need to sublass something (either a model ora a delegate), so they both seem to have the same difficulty...

Comment: This approach would need a UserRole that can be used for sorting, numbers are sorted different than strings.